# Debian/Ubuntu Java 11 java-alternative

Tags: debian, tomcat8, java-11

I upgraded my debian to bionic and I have a problem with java.  It has upgraded my java to jdk11 which is causing problems with missing EE modules so I want to make jdk8 the default.  I've done:

- I've tried changing the java alternative to jdk8 and that works for /usr/bin/java but the tomcat8 script uses /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java and this is not updated with the java-alternative command.
- I've tried uninstalling java 11 but apt keeps saying that it is not installed.
- I've tried setting JAVA_HOME in the tomcat script but that isn't working either.

  Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - tomcat searches for a jvm and prefers higher numbers in the /etc/init.d/tomcat8 script.  It never looks for the default java.